# Safari not displaying web page (works in IE, Chrome, and Firefox)

Tags: html, css, safari, rendering, server

I've updated a website for a client and am having rendering issues in Safari. Here is a link http://vrbart.com/

When I tested the file on my server in various versions of Chrome, IE, Safari it worked great no font issues or layout issues — it's a linux server.

Last night I uploaded the files to her host site and went through different browsers, all worked, one font wasn't showing, but when I went to Safari 5 and 8 most of the site pages are missing. Content appears to be there but style sheet isn't rendering. I believe the server her site is on is running apache. Thanks for any help in advance to her host?

1. Could I have done something wrong in the upload process?
2. Is it a server issue?

Comment: I get another issue on Safari. A lot of text is missing, but there's also some spacing problems (possibly caused by a font issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `MuseoSans_500-webfont.ttf` is corrupted. `Woff` format is displayed properly but Safari on OS X uses `ttf` format.

[image: Museo font]

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked. it seams to be working on my side.

I would be a cache problem or something

But this promblem can comme from the server having not the same config as your local wamp/mamp or what ever

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a font issue, stripped out MuseoSans from the stylesheet and everything is fixed. Found it odd the fallback wasn't working in Safari. As an example I had this for paragraphs. So in IE, Chrome, and Firefox I was seeing helvetica or arial, but nothing in Safari.

```
p {
font-family: 'museo_sans500', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 22px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
```

}

Also got this message from the server when I tried to upload the Museo fonts again "FTP error: Cannot create folder MuseoSansItalic. 550 can't create directory, disk quota exceeded."

Comment: On Safari the fallback failed because the browser was actually loading the corrupted font. But the font was missing glyphs.